# How to clear cell value on specifi row and column in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Im am trying to clear a cell value except the first row and the second column in vb.net.
[image]

I did tried

```
For i = 0 To dgvSchedule.Rows.Count - 1
     If (dgvSchedule.Columns(i).Name = "Column3" Or dgvSchedule.Columns(i).Name = "Column4" Or dgvSchedule.Columns(i).Name = "Column5") And
         dgvSchedule.RowCount >= 1 Then
         dgvSchedule.Rows(1).Cells(i).Value = "0.00"
     End If
Next
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: You are using row index from for loop (`i`) as column index, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @Fabio, I just want to clear the values inside the highlighted part. any possible solution would be a great help.

Comment: Maybe: `For Each row In dgvSchedule.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Skip(1) : For Each col In dgvSchedule.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).Skip(2) : dgvSchedule(col.Index, row.Index).Value = "0.00" : Next : Next` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To dgvSchedule.RowCount - 1
    For j = 0 To dgvSchedule.Columns.Count - 1
        If dgvSchedule.Rows(i).Index > 1 And dgvSchedule.Columns(j).Index > 0 Then
            dgvSchedule.Item(j, i).Value =  "0.00"
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: The `Row` should be `> 0` and the `Column` should be `> 1`. Alternatively, start the `i` loop with 1 and the `j` loop with 2 and remove the `If..End If`.